# OpenERP/Odoo - Quote inside a string is not working - cr.execute(SQL)

Tags: python, sql, odoo

In OpenERP 7 , I am using a cr.execute to execute a SQL Request

```
cr.execute('select distinct(value) from ir_translation where name = \'product.bat3,name\' and src = \''+ str(res_bat[j][0].encode('utf-8'))+'\' and res_id = '+ str(res_bat[j][1])+' and lang = \''+ str(line2.partner_id.lang)+'\'')
```

However, my string res_bat[j][0] is a string with a 
quote. The string is: **test's**
Thus I have the error bellow:

```
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "s"
LINE 1: ... where name = 'product.bat3,name' and src = 'test's' and res...
```

How can I modify my SQL request to correct this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must not perform the substitutions yourself in a SQL query as this makes your code vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

The correct version is:

```
cr.execute(
    'select distinct(value) from ir_translation '
    'where name = %s and src = %s  and res_id = %S and lang = %s', 
    ('product.bat3,name',
     res_bat[j][0].encode('utf-8'),
     res_bat[j][1],
     line2.partner_id.lang)
)
```

You may keep the first parameter in the query if you wish.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!